# Bash Scripting and quotation

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I'm reading a couple of books on bash scripting, and struggling to understand proper quotation and the use of `IFS`.  Perhaps someone can help me with a small example involving filenames with quotes.  Doing this from a command line, this works to print out the filenames properly, even if they include spaces:

```
set - *
for i in "$@"; do echo $i; done
```

This does not work, as it breaks at spaces:

```
set - `find . -name "*"`
for i in "$@"; do echo $i; done
```

Nor does:

```
IFS=$'\0' set - `find . -name "*" -print0`
for i in "$@"; do echo $i; done
```

Nor does the combination that uses `IFS=$'\n'` and `-print`.  Why do these all fail?

The following also fails, but in this case it errors out ("bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'").  Why?

```
IFS=$'\n' for i in `find . -name "*" -type f`; do echo $i; done
```

but this works (notice the ";"):

```
IFS=$'\n'; for i in `find . -name "*" -type f`; do echo $i; done
```

and this fails because the filenames aren't split at all (the `for` loops only once):

```
IFS=''; for i in `find . -name "*" -type f -print0`; do echo -e "$i\n"; done
```

So again, why do the first and third ones there fail?

Finally, am I correct in my belief that when setting `IFS`, `''` is the same as `$'\0'`?  (I tried both in that immediately previous example.)  If so, why do I apparently need `$'\n'` rather than just `\n`?

*Bash is version 4.3.42(1) in Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.

Comment: Bash is version 4.3.42(1) in Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.  It fails to print out the filenames correctly.  It breaks them at spaces when it should be breaking at newlines.  I tried `IFS=$'\n' set - `find . -name "*" -print`` and `for i in "$@"; do echo $i; done`.  It definitely does not work.

Comment: Ah, I see.  You have a `;` after the `IFS=...`  I don't.  That's like the second case in the second group of 3.  The question is, why is that needed?  I expect that without the `;`, the modification of the variable should be temporary, within the following command.  I don't want it to be permanent.

Comment: In respond to why ``IFS=$'\n'; set - `find`;`` work but not ``IFS=$'\n' set - `find`;``. A plausible explanation is that in ``IFS=$'\n' set - `find`;``, `find` is substitued and tokenized with current IFS before `set` is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Two things I've learned when debugging bash commands:  One) If it's not working like you think it should, echo/printf out the commands to ensure they display the way you think they should.  Two) Manually run the commands you have within your commands to see if they run properly, (unless these are potentially destructive commands, such as: rm, dd, chmod 777, etc.).

How or what exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Mine seems to work fine with that command verbatim, so you'll need to explain what you want it to do.  Do you have spaces in your filenames that are causing issues with your command?  So long as you get rid of the space from the IFS variable, it probably work the way you want: `IFS=$'\n\t'`.  The `-print0` option basically strips out all of the line separators, so everything that you want from those commands has no separators at all unless the files have spaces in their names.
For your second set of questions:

```
IFS=$'\n' for i in `find . -name "*" -type f`; do echo $i; done
```

This command doesn't run properly because bash reads it like this:

```
IFS=$'\n' for i in `find . -name "*" -type f`
do echo $i
done
```

The first line sets IFS to: `$'\n' for i in`.  After that, the next line reads as: `do echo $i`, which doesn't work since the `do` command requires a loop of some sort to be the preceding command.
The next one works because the semicolon tells bash that the end of the command has been reached so:

```
IFS=$'\n'
for i in `find . -name "*" -type f`
do echo $i
done
```

> Finally, am I correct in my belief that when setting IFS, '' is the same as $'\0'? (I tried both in that immediately previous example.) If so, why do I apparently need $'\n' rather than just \n?

Yes to the first part, `''` and `'\0'` are both considered NULL, so they are basically the same.  This is due to bash interpreting `$''` as an ANSI C string.  And you need to have quotes around the \n to have bash interpret it as a C string so that a newline character is placed in the IFS.
You can read up more about these [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting).

Comment: Yes, there are spaces in the filenames, and that is the issue (I clarified above).  (1) Getting rid of the spaces in the IFS is not working with `set`.  I am certain.  (2) My understanding was that `var=value <command>` should set `var` to the value temporarily when the command is run.  Here the command is a `for`, no?  (3) The last command does have a `;` after the `IFS=`, but it still doesn't work even though `-print0` should produce null separated filenames.

Comment: Yes, the `-print0` command should append null characters instead of newlines; however bash is automagically removing them.  You'll need to save the output to a file if you want to keep them; however I'm not sure this is what you'll want as Bash will remove null characters if you try to use them.  Bash will not allow null characters in variables as you can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570531/assign-string-containing-null-character-0-to-a-variable-in-bash).

Comment: That is strange.  It also appears to mean that `IFS=''` doesn't work, because I can't set IFS to ``\0``

Comment: So in that case, in the examples using `set`, the only thing left that perplexes me is that `IFS=$'\n' set - \`find . -name "*" -print\`` fails, breaking file names at spaces.

Comment: Setting <code>IFS=''</code> is the same as blanking it out.  Since bash ignores null characters, there's no reason to check for them; which then means that there's no extra argument separation at all.  You can put whatever you want in <code>IFS</code> and bash will interpret it as an extra argument break, (characters, not strings).  As for your second comment, <code>IFS</code> isn't being set the way you want until after the command finishes.  Put a semicolon between <code>IFS=$'\n'</code> and <code>set - `find . -name "*" -print`</code> and that should fix your issue.